# Table and Proc dependency

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am new to schema and not sure how the table is being populated  (How the data is being inserted into the table ). How can we find out ?

This should work.

```
select *
from dba_source
where upper(text) like '%TABLE_NAME%'
```

But as I do not have DBA rights , can not execute this command. What is the other way to find this out ?

Answer (score 1):

To see dependencies between objects you have access to you can query [the `all_dependencies` data dictionary view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1069.htm). In this case:

```
select * from all_dependencies where referenced_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
```

If the objects are in your own schema when you can use the `user_dependencies` view. If you want to see objects you don't have privileges against then you can use `dba_dependencies`, but it sounds like you are unlikely to have the privileges required to query that view, since you can't see `dba_source`.

Of course, that will only identify references within your stored PL/SQL code; it won't tell you about any external application code that is performing inserts directly against the database (as opposed to via CRUD procedures) or manual inserts.

And it will only tell you which objects have dependencies, you'll still need to dig through the object source code, either by querying `all_source` (or `user_source` if you're the owner) for the relevant type and name. I would avoid the possibility of false-positives from, say, comments that happen to mention the table name in code which doesn't access it. You could also do that outside the database - hopefully your code is under source control (right!?).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the query you need to run but do not have the necessary privileges then perhaps you can write the query using USER_ or ALL_ views to validate the syntax then change the view to DBA_ and ask the DBA to run the query for you.